# Solve: $\frac{dy}{dx}+y\tan x=y^3 \cos x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Bernoulli's Equation:**

Solve: $\frac{dy}{dx}+y\tan x=y^3 \cos x$

Is my solution correct?

[image]

[image]

Comment: One solution is given by $$y(x)=-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{\sqrt{6 c_1 \sec ^2(x)-\sin (3
   x) \sec ^2(x)-9 \tan (x) \sec (x)}}$$

Comment: Please try not to post your work as images, otherwise some user may not be able to see.

Comment: It's correct to me. Good job.